# How do I combine two dictionaries based on their values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have two dictionaries containing nucleotide strings as the key and their counts as the value.

example:

```
dict1 = {GGA:64231, GAT: 66582}
dict2 = {TCC:64231, ATC: 66582}
```

I want to make a new dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict3 = {'GGA:TCC':64231, 'GAT:ATC':66582}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if one of the dicts has two keys with the same value?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want your dictionaries to map the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply swap the key/value pairs in the dictionary to build your new one (assuming you have unique values, and your dictionaries all have matching values):

Python 3:

```
dict1 = {'GGA':64231, 'GAT': 66582}
dict1 = {v:k for k,v in dict1.items()} # {66582: 'GAT', 64231: 'GGA'}
dict2 = {'TCC':64231, 'ATC': 66582}
dict2 = {v:k for k,v in dict2.items()} # {66582: 'ATC', 64231: 'TCC'}
dict3 = {"{}:{}".format(dict1[k],dict2[k]):k for k in dict1} # {'GGA:TCC': 64231, 'GAT:ATC': 66582}
```

Python 2.7 use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`

Comment: Is this python 2.7? I got invalid syntax errors. I'm using python3.6.

Comment: Why not simply `{ v: k for k, v in d.items() }` for swapping the dicts?

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to try using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'GGA':64231, 'GAT': 66582}
dict2 = {'TCC':64231, 'ATC': 66582}

result_dict = defaultdict(list)
# read first dictionary and add value as key and key to list of values
for k, v in dict1.items(): result_dict[v].append(k)

# read other dictionary and add value as key and key to list of values 
for k, v in dict2.items(): result_dict[v].append(k)

# change key to value in dicitonary
result_dict = {':'.join(v):k for k, v in result_dict.items()}
print(result_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'GAT:ATC': 66582, 'GGA:TCC': 64231}
```

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't put `for` loops on one line, the indentation helps readability.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do that is using list comprehension, which I believe is more pythonic:

```
dict1 = {GGA:64231, GAT: 66582}
dict2 = {TCC:64231, ATC: 66582}

new_dict = { x+":"+y:dict1[x] for x in dict1.keys() for y in dict2.keys() if dict1[x] == dict2[y]}
```

And this is the output:

```
{'GGA:TCC': 64231, 'GAT:ATC': 66582}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be smarter to map them with the key as the numbers for example since they are the defining factor.

```
a={i:[w] for w,i in dict1.items()}
b={i:w if i not in a else a[i]+[w] for w,i in dict2.items()}
```

**output**

```
{64231: ['GGA', 'TCC'], 66582: ['GAT', 'ATC']}
```

or in your case

```
a={i:[w] for w,i in dict1.items()}
b={i:w if i not in a else ":".join(a[i]+[w]) for w,i in dict2.items()}
```

**output**

```
{64231: 'GGA:TCC', 66582: 'GAT:ATC'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for an assignment that requires the keys and values be in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

What a fun little problem. My version doesn't search the dict, it assumes your dicts have perfect information and the values can be sorted by the number value.

```
dict1 = {"GGA": 64231, "GAT": 66582}
dict2 = {"TCC": 64231, "ATC": 66582}

dict3 = {
    "%s:%s" % (k, l): v
    for (k, v), (l, b) in zip(
        sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]),
        sorted(dict2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]),
    )
}
print(dict3)
```

I'll say though @TheoretiCAL's answer is likely the best.

Comment: So I got an error with yours: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" and I think this is because you wrote it assuming there were only two items in the dictionaries. I'm actually trying to run this over really large dictionaries where I don't know how many k:v pairs there are.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you're calling `items` on the dicts? My solution does assume your input data is "perfect" so it is a little brittle, but it scales to more than 2 elements.